# use .NET reflection to know if a method is not a set property and not from a base class

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am using a [castle windsor interceptor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md) to try and start and finish a transaction for all public methods.

I have this `Intercept` method:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    MethodInfo method;
    try
    {
        method = invocation.MethodInvocationTarget;
    }
    catch
    {
        method = invocation.GetConcreteMethod();
    }

    if (!method.IsPublic)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!((IList) new[] {"ncontinuity2.core", "c2.bases"}).Contains(method.DeclaringType.Assembly.GetName().Name))
    {
        return;
    }


    PerformUow(invocation);
}
```

I cannot find a way of excluding property set methods, for example, I have this property in a base class:

```
public virtual Context Context
{
    get { return _context; }
    set
    {
        _context = value;
    }
}
```

I would like to exclude properties like this `Set_Context`.

How can I tell it is a property and is there a way to know if this in a base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell whether a method is inherited or not, you can compare the `DeclaringType` with the actual object type. I'm not sure about the Castle-Windsor part, but it should be something like this

```
invocation.TargetType == method.DeclaringType
```

For property accessors the `IsSpecialName` property is equal to `true`.

```
!method.IsSpecialName
```

together

```
if (invocation.TargetType == method.DeclaringType && !method.IsSpecialName) {
    // We have a non-inherited method not being a property accessor.
}
```